# Avoid MySQL Connection during Websocket

Tags: mysql, go, websocket

**I have a question regarding the flow of go lang code.**

- In my `main` function, I am opening `mysql` connection and then using `defer" to close the connection at the end of the connection.
- I have `route` where `WebSocket` is set up and used.

My Question is will program open connection every time, WebSocket is used to send and receive a message or will it just open once the page was loaded.

Here is how my code looks like:-

```
package main

import (
    // Loading various package
)

func main() {

    // Opening DB connection   -> *sql.DB
    db := openMySql()

    // Closing DB connection
    defer db.Close()

    // Route for "websocket" end point
    app.Get("/ws", wsHandler(db))

    // Another route using "WebSocket" endpoint.
    app.Get("/message", message(db))
}
```

Now, while a user is at "`message`" route, whenever he is sending the message to other users, Will `mysql` - `open` and `close` connection event will happen every time, when the message is being sent and receive using "`/ws`" route?

Or will it happen Just once? whenever "`/message`" route and "`/ws`" event is called the first time.

- My Purpose of using "`db`" in "`wsHandler`" function is to verify and check if the user has permission to send a message to the particular room or not.
- But there is no point opening and closing connection every second while `WebSocket` emits `message` or `typing` event.

**What would be the best way to handle permission checking in "/ws" route, if above code is horror?** Considering a fact there will be few hundred thousand concurrent users.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `db` is [*sql.DB](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB) your code seems fine, I'm also assuming that your example is incomplete and your `main` does not actually return right away.

The docs on [Open](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open) state:

> The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and
>   maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function
>   should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB.

So `wsHandler` and `message` should be ok to use it as they please as long as they don't close DB themselves.

Comment: My question is, "will db open and close" will happen every time, websocket receives message or will it happen only once when the page is loaded and websocket connection is established ?

Comment: `DB` maintains a **pool of connection**, as far as I understand that means that if no connection is available `DB` will open one but it will not close it after it becomes idle, instead it will retain the idle connection and reuse it the next time some code needs it. You also need to keep in mind that all this is ultimately dependent on how the db driver that you are using is implemented.

Comment: Btw if by "will db open and close" you mean the `openMySql()` and `defer db.Close()` lines, then No, the `main` func is executed only once.

Comment: Is it really idle to check mysql every time whether the user is associated with particular room or group? Is there any better alternative way without hitting high connection issue or slowing down performance.

Do you suggest NoSQL against such thing or MySQL can perform better ? considering memory DB store is not an option. I saw the comparison of MariaDB and MySQL in golang and found MySQL performing better than MariaDB.

Comment: I'm not familiar with NoSQL vs SQL in the context of a chat app, or outside of that context for that matter. I'm also not that familiar with the details of how a specific driver implements the connection handling but generally a connection should become idle as soon as its work is done. If you're worried about performance you should profile your program under real-world load and go from there.